# is clipboard api removed from gtk4?

Tags: linux, gtk, x11, gtk3, gnome

During search the clipboard api in gnome. Only find clipboard api in gtk3. it seems that the clipboard api was removed from gtk4.

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtkbase.html

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/gtkbase.html

Comment: Shouldn't you ask the vendor?

Comment: yes, thanks, I forget about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it has been removed. The lack of documentation seems to be an oversight: this really should be mentioned in the Migration section...

You may be able to use the GDK clipboard API instead: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk4/stable/gdk4-Clipboards.html